# How to access facebook.yml credentials from anywhere in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a facebook.yml, twitter.yml, etc containing relevant tokens for development, production, staging environments.

I then have methods such as

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/facebook.yml"))[Rails.env]
FB_APP_ID = CONFIG['app_id']
FB_SECRET = CONFIG['secret_key']
FB_NAMESPACE = CONFIG['name_space']
```

How and where should I set up these methods so that I can access FB_APP_ID from anywhere else in my app: controllers, models, views, etc?

Is this where modules come in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a config.yml file

```
development:
  facebook: 
    app_id:  #####
    secret: ###
  twitter:
    --
production:
  ---
etc
```

Added initializers/config.rb

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/config.yml"))[Rails.env]

module Facebook
  APP_ID = FB_CONFIG["facebook"]['app_id']
  SECRET = FB_CONFIG["facebook"]['secret']
end

module Twitter
  --
end
```

Now I can access these values anywhere using

```
Facebook::APP_ID
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but its working for now.